# overloading operator for string in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, wchar-t

I have a class named `Fstring`, it has a `wchar_t*` in it.

I wrote the following to copy the string literal into `Fstring`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Fstring{
    wchar_t *arr;
public:

    Fstring& operator = (const wchar_t temp[])
    {
        delete [] arr;
        arr=new wchar_t[wcslen(temp)];
        for(int i=0;i<=wcslen(temp);i++)
            arr[i]=temp[i];
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Fstring test=L"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

But it did not work.  The compiler gave me the following error:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [12]'
>   to 'Fstring'

I'm really confused, I googled "Overloading operators" but all of results have the same way I used to overload the operator.  So why does this not work?

Comment: Why not just use `std::wstring`?

Comment: `Fstring test=L"Hello World";` calls a constructor not `operator=`  as you are constructing a new `Fstring`.

Comment: You may want to implement a constructor as well.

Comment: oh ... i thought constructor called just when we put something in () like this: `Fstring test(L"Hello World");` thanks for your help

Comment: See `std::copy` instead of using your own loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see `Type name = initializer` it does not use the assignment operator.  It is declaring a variable and is therefore initialization(technically *copy-initialization* or *copy-list-initialization*).  That means it calls a constructor.  Since you do not have a constructor that takes a `const wchar_t*` you will get an error.

What you need is to implement a constructor that takes a `const wchar_t*` and initialize `arr` with that.  That would look like

```
Fstring(const wchar_t temp*) : arr(new wchar_t[wcslen(temp) + 1])
{
    size_t size = wcslen(temp);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    arr[size] = L'\0'
}
```

You are also going to have to implement a copy constructor.  For more on why see [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

---

Do note that you are reinventing the wheel.  If you want a wide character string you can use [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) which has all this done for you.